# Get data from Parse.File via beforeSave

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, parse-platform, parse-server

I want to fetch the data from the `BeforeSaveRequest.object.icon` when the icon is a `Parse.File`.

But the problem is that the Parse.File doesn't contain any data attribute or function, and we cannot fetch the file before it was saved.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I can use the `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` in order to fetch the file, even if it comes from the BeforeSaveRequest.

I've noticed that the file is being saved before it reaches to the request.

```
var parseFile = request.object.get("image");

function httpRequest(parseFile, method, callback) {
  var url = parseFile.url();
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    "GET",
    url,
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(`Data: ${response.buffer}`
  }, function(response) {
    // Error
  });
}
```